# AdMob request fail

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm running an app with AdMob ads. It works nicely, but sometimes the server can't serve an ad, so I thought about serving my own ads (plain images served from my own server). Is there any way to set a callback to the AdRequest so if the request fails, the callback is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for AdMob's [AdListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#adlistener):

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

Specifically, the `onFailedToReceiveAd` callback tells you when AdMob couldn't return an ad. Have your class implement this interface to get all these callbacks. Just don't forget to set the `AdListener` on your `AdView`:

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```