# Showing Admob interstitials when moving from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, admob

According to the doc: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

I am requesting from one activity,

```
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

And show the interstitial when it is received in the callback

```
 @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
```

Butt the problem is before `onReceiveAd` is being called, my current activity is finished and I moved to another activity, so `onReceiveAd` is never being called.

Any workaround to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The simple solution is to just not call the next activity until you get one of the callbacks(whether it's received/failed).

Comment: It is not possible or it will block the user UI, becoz sometime the fill rate is less than 100%, that means no ads is available ..

Comment: Right. That's why you do it on the "failed" callback, also. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13039350/752320) for details.

Answer (score 0):

have you found an answer to this?
I'm planning to do this but I haven't tried yet so I'm not sure it will work:

On a Helper class create a static method for creating the interstitial ad, and another for updating the listener:

```
    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public static void createIntertitialAd(Context myContext) {
        if (interstitial == null) {
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(myContext, MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
           interstitial.setAdListener(myContext);
        }
    }

    public static void updateAdListener(Context myContext) {
        interstitial.setAdListener(myContext);
    }
```

Then on your activities do the following

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        HelperClass.createIntertitialAd(this);
        HelperClass.updateAdListener(this);
    }
```